# Fatal error: Class 'Predis\Client' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis, predis

I'm using `codeigniter` framework.
I want to use `redis` on my project.

to do this I find this library:

```
https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis
```

I installed it with composer.

now I want to use it:

```
  $client = new Predis\Client();
```

but I got this message:

```
Message: Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

I set up these configs:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = '/vendor/autoload.php';
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

[image]

my OS is windows 7. somewhere says I should install redis on my windows because I'm using localhost. yeah?

**updated**
[image]

Comment: are you loaded the redis library?

Comment: How can I load this library? I just installed with composer.

Comment: follow these instruction https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis

Comment: `This library is deprecated. We recommend migrating to Predis`

Comment: add this line to your controller constructor `require 'Predis/Autoloader.php';`

Comment: I haven't this directory `Predis/Autoloader.php`

Comment: show us inside view of vendor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and `vendor` inside application directory and leave `$config['composer_autoload'] = ''` empty. It is recommended since that way someone won't be allowed reading what external libraries/packages your application uses. Also `APPPATH.'vendor'` is default CI location (by [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L126-L127)).

If you for some reason want to have `composer.json` in publicly accessible location, try your existing configuration with this change:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Also, have you put

```
use Predis\Client as PredisClient;//for distinctive use of Client word in case of Guzzle, other libs, etc.
```

before controller class code? After that you can use it as

```
$client = new PredisClient();
```

Check if all of this works.